# D3 Force Layout Graph - Self linking node

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

Using a force directed graph, how do you get a link to actually show up when the target and source are the same node.  So basically just a nice little loop indicating that such an edge exists.

There are two D3 examples that I already used or tried to use:

- I'm using http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5155181 to show direction, and
  the little endpoint arrow will show up pointing at itself, but no
  link line.
- http://bl.ocks.org/GerHobbelt/3616279 does does allow for self
  referencing and I even sort of got it to work with my data, but it is
  crazy complicated.

Comment: You would need to define an appropriate path (the "d" attribute) for the self-referencing nodes, i.e. something with intermediate points and suitable interpolation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The trick is to draw the self link as a path with an arc in it.  It took me a bit of fiddling with the [arc parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) to get things working and the key seemed to be that the arc could not start and end at the same point.  Here is the relevant code that draws the edges at each update.

```
function tick() {
  link.attr("d", function(d) {
  var x1 = d.source.x,
      y1 = d.source.y,
      x2 = d.target.x,
      y2 = d.target.y,
      dx = x2 - x1,
      dy = y2 - y1,
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),

      // Defaults for normal edge.
      drx = dr,
      dry = dr,
      xRotation = 0, // degrees
      largeArc = 0, // 1 or 0
      sweep = 1; // 1 or 0

      // Self edge.
      if ( x1 === x2 && y1 === y2 ) {
        // Fiddle with this angle to get loop oriented.
        xRotation = -45;

        // Needs to be 1.
        largeArc = 1;

        // Change sweep to change orientation of loop. 
        //sweep = 0;

        // Make drx and dry different to get an ellipse
        // instead of a circle.
        drx = 30;
        dry = 20;

        // For whatever reason the arc collapses to a point if the beginning
        // and ending points of the arc are the same, so kludge it.
        x2 = x2 + 1;
        y2 = y2 + 1;
      } 

 return "M" + x1 + "," + y1 + "A" + drx + "," + dry + " " + xRotation + "," + largeArc + "," + sweep + " " + x2 + "," + y2;
});
```

And here is [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUrKR/) that demonstrates the whole thing, and a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Just adding; if you want the rest of the links just to be normal straight links, set `drx` and `dry` to `0` for normal links :)

Comment: would be interesting to make this link avoid overlaps with other nodes, not sure this allows that but really appreciate this example