# Find cycles in force directed graph

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

i want to find cycles in force directed graph. D3JS have method to detect loops in graph ([article with method / parameter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3.force-link-status)) . It is possible use this function and visualize loops ? I have graph with arrows (source - taget direction) like is here [Graph](https://vida.io/documents/Sb6qisLx9aWbuWgxr)

Thanks for help!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17687907/1423333