# D3 self linking edges

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code I got from the net. I am trying to build a graph that has self linking nodes.

After much struggle I was able to do it for edges linking to other nodes. Can someone plz help me to create a self linking edge?

I tried integrating the example [D3 Force Layout Graph - Self linking node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358905/d3-force-layout-graph-self-linking-node)
But could not suceed. Please help.

And thanks in advance

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Force Layout with labels on edges</title>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var w = 1400;
    var h = 600;
    //distance between nodes
    var linkDistance=200;

    var colors = d3.scale.category10();

    var dataset = {

    nodes: [
    {name: "Car"},
    {name: "Jeep"}
    ],
    edges: [
    {source: 0, target: 0}
    ],
    methlbl: [
    {name:"add(int, int)"}
    ]
    };

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({"width":w,"height":h});

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(dataset.nodes)
        .links(dataset.edges)
        .size([w,h])
        .linkDistance([linkDistance])
        .charge([-500])
        .theta(0.1)
        .gravity(0.05)
        .start();



    var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
      .data(dataset.edges)
      .enter()
      .append("line")
      .attr("id",function(d,i) {return 'edge'+i})
      .attr('marker-end','url(#arrowhead)')
      .style("stroke","#ccc")
      .style("pointer-events", "none");

    var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(dataset.nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr({"r":15})
      .style("fill",function(d,i){return colors(4);})
      .call(force.drag)


    var nodelabels = svg.selectAll(".nodelabel") 
       .data(dataset.nodes)
       .enter()
       .append("text")
       .attr({"x":function(d){return d.x;},
              "y":function(d){return d.y;},
              "class":"nodelabel",
              "stroke":"black"})
       .text(function(d){return d.name;});

    var edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath")
        .data(dataset.edges)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr({'d': function(d) {return 'M '+d.source.x+' '+d.source.y+' L '+ d.target.x +' '+d.target.y},
               'class':'edgepath',
               'fill-opacity':0,
               'stroke-opacity':0,
               'fill':'blue',
               'stroke':'red',
               'id':function(d,i) {return 'edgepath'+i}})
        .style("pointer-events", "none");

    var edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel")
        .data(dataset.edges)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attr({'class':'edgelabel',
               'id':function(d,i){return 'edgelabel'+i},
               'dx':40,
               'dy':-10,
               'font-size':20,
               'fill':'#aaa'});

    edgelabels.append('textPath')
        .attr('xlink:href',function(d,i) {return '#edgepath'+i})
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .text(function(d,i){return dataset.methlbl[i].name});


    svg.append('defs').append('marker')
        .attr({'id':'arrowhead',
               'viewBox':'-0 -5 10 10',
               'refX':25,
               'refY':0,
               //'markerUnits':'strokeWidth',
               'orient':'auto',
               'markerWidth':10,
               'markerHeight':10,
               'xoverflow':'visible'})
        .append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
            .attr('fill', '#ccc')
            .attr('stroke','#ccc');


    force.on("tick", function(){

        edges.attr({"x1": function(d){return d.source.x;},
                    "y1": function(d){return d.source.y;},
                    "x2": function(d){return d.target.x;},
                    "y2": function(d){return d.target.y;}
        });

        nodes.attr({"cx":function(d){return d.x;},
                    "cy":function(d){return d.y;}
        });

        nodelabels.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; }) 
                  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });

        edgepaths.attr('d', function(d) { var path='M '+d.source.x+' '+d.source.y+' L '+ d.target.x +' '+d.target.y;
                                           //console.log(d)
                                           return path});       
        edgelabels.attr('transform',function(d,i){
            if (d.target.x<d.source.x){
                bbox = this.getBBox();
                rx = bbox.x+bbox.width/2;
                ry = bbox.y+bbox.height/2;
                return 'rotate(180 '+rx+' '+ry+')';
                }
            else {
                return 'rotate(0)';
                }
        });
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed unnecessary code and made some improvements. Hope following code snippet helps.

```js
var w = 800;
var h = 400;
//distance between nodes
var linkDistance = 200;

var colors = d3.scale.category10();

var dataset = {

  nodes: [{
      name: "Car"
    },
    {
      name: "Jeep"
    }
  ],
  edges: [{
    source: 0,
    target: 0
  }],
  methlbl: [{
    name: "add(int, int)"
  }]
};

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({
  "width": w,
  "height": h
});

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(dataset.nodes)
  .links(dataset.edges)
  .size([w, h])
  .linkDistance([linkDistance])
  .charge([-500])
  .theta(0.1)
  .gravity(0.05)
  .start();

var edges = svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(dataset.edges)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .style("fill","none")
  .attr("id", function(d, i) {
    return 'edge' + i
  })
  .attr('marker-end', function(d) {
    return d.source == d.target ? '' : 'url(#arrowhead)'
  })
  .style("stroke", "#ccc")
  .style("pointer-events", "none");

var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(dataset.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr({
    "r": 15
  })
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors(4);
  })
  .call(force.drag)


var nodelabels = svg.selectAll(".nodelabel")
  .data(dataset.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr({
    "x": function(d) {
      return d.x;
    },
    "y": function(d) {
      return d.y;
    },
    "class": "nodelabel",
    "stroke": "black"
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });

var edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel")
  .data(dataset.edges)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .style("pointer-events", "none")
  .attr({
    'class': 'edgelabel',
    'id': function(d, i) {
      return 'edgelabel' + i
    },
    'font-size': 20,
    'fill': '#aaa'
  })


edgelabels.append("textPath")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
    return '#edge' + i;
  })
  .style("pointer-events", "none")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return dataset.methlbl[i].name
  });


svg.append('defs').append('marker')
  .attr({
    'id': 'arrowhead',
    'viewBox': '-0 -5 10 10',
    'refX': 25,
    'refY': 0,
    'orient': 'auto',
    'markerWidth': 10,
    'markerHeight': 10,
    'xoverflow': 'visible'
  })
  .append('svg:path')
  .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
  .attr('fill', '#ccc')
  .attr('stroke', '#ccc');


force.on("tick", function() {


  edges.attr("d", function(d) {
    var x1 = d.source.x,
      y1 = d.source.y,
      x2 = d.target.x,
      y2 = d.target.y,
      dx = x2 - x1,
      dy = y2 - y1,
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),

      // Defaults for normal edge.
      drx = dr,
      dry = dr,
      xRotation = 0, // degrees
      largeArc = 0, // 1 or 0
      sweep = 1; // 1 or 0

    // Self edge.
    if (x1 === x2 && y1 === y2) {
      // Fiddle with this angle to get loop oriented.
      xRotation = -45;

      // Needs to be 1.
      largeArc = 1;

      // Change sweep to change orientation of loop. 
      //sweep = 0;

      // Make drx and dry different to get an ellipse
      // instead of a circle.
      drx = 30;
      dry = 20;

      // For whatever reason the arc collapses to a point if the beginning
      // and ending points of the arc are the same, so kludge it.
      x2 = x2 + 1;
      y2 = y2 + 1;
    }

    return "M" + x1 + "," + y1 + "A" + drx + "," + dry + " " + xRotation + "," + largeArc + "," + sweep + " " + x2 + "," + y2;
  });

  nodes.attr({
    "cx": function(d) {
      return d.x;
    },
    "cy": function(d) {
      return d.y;
    }
  });

  edgelabels.selectAll("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
      return '#edge' + i;
    })
    .attr("startOffset", function(d, i) {
      var arcLength = d3.select("#edge" + i).node().getTotalLength();
      var textLength = d3.select("#edgelabel" + i).node().getComputedTextLength();
      var offset = (arcLength - textLength) / 2;
      return offset;
    });
  nodelabels.attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. This is what I wanted. Looks like I will not be able to pick D3 up. I dont know how to modify the code to include my full requirement. Thanks again.

Comment: How about if I connect to a different node?? This still shows half arc.

Comment: This code should work for both self linking nodes and nodes connecting to other nodes. I just tried changing one of the source or target attributes and it worked as expected. Could you tell me what is the exact issue you face??

Comment: ok so the thing I observed is, in IE there is no fill however, in FF i see a fill. Plz access this link in ff.  [link]https://jsfiddle.net/praveen_alvandi/bk1ru6md/

Comment: Add style 'fill:none' to each path attribute. Updated in the snippet.This should fix the problem.

Comment: These codes do not fit in the 7.x version. This is giving me a headache