# Is there a D3 similar to the GoJS State Chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, gojs

For my use case I want something close to this. 
https://gojs.net/latest/samples/stateChart.html

I have nodes in a list of ids & relationship in form of a list of to & from and relationship name.

The example is a perfect fit but sadly it is in goJs,

Is there a ready-made something similar to this in D3? or any other free to use libraries I can leverage on?

Here is the data from the goJs example, I have similar data.

```
{ "nodeKeyProperty": "id",
  "nodeDataArray": [
    { "id": 0, "loc": "120 120", "text": "Initial" },
    { "id": 1, "loc": "330 120", "text": "First down" },
    { "id": 2, "loc": "226 376", "text": "First up" },
    { "id": 3, "loc": "60 276", "text": "Second down" },
    { "id": 4, "loc": "226 226", "text": "Wait" }
  ],
  "linkDataArray": [
    { "from": 0, "to": 0, "text": "up or timer", "curviness": -20 },
    { "from": 0, "to": 1, "text": "down", "curviness": 20 },
    { "from": 1, "to": 0, "text": "up (moved)\nPOST", "curviness": 20 },
    { "from": 1, "to": 1, "text": "down", "curviness": -20 },
    { "from": 1, "to": 2, "text": "up (no move)" },
    { "from": 1, "to": 4, "text": "timer" },
    { "from": 2, "to": 0, "text": "timer\nPOST" },
    { "from": 2, "to": 3, "text": "down" },
    { "from": 3, "to": 0, "text": "up\nPOST\n(dblclick\nif no move)" },
    { "from": 3, "to": 3, "text": "down or timer", "curviness": 20 },
    { "from": 4, "to": 0, "text": "up\nPOST" },
    { "from": 4, "to": 4, "text": "down" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 Force Layout Graph - Self linking node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358905/d3-force-layout-graph-self-linking-node)

Comment: You basically want a self-linking node whose link starting and end at the same point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358905/d3-force-layout-graph-self-linking-node

Comment: Nope, please check the goJs example. I want all those features, adding/deleting node, relations. And such a state diagram.

Comment: Maybe you should try to see how far d3.js can go for you, before coming back with a specific problem statement? Right now you’re just asking a really broad question.

Comment: @RudraRoy Have you found any alternative to gojs?

Comment: @hetellla No :(